# can't run protractor tests on macOS Sierra, Safari 10.0.2

Tags: protractor

I'm getting a `UnsupportedOperationError: Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'` when i run my protractor 5.0.0 tests on safari.
I have a webdriver 2.48.0 extension enabled in safari.

conf file:

```
capabilities: {
    name: 'Safari',
    browserName: 'safari',
    logName: 'Safari',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 2
  }
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
```

I'm starting the server manually by
`./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager start`

and running the spec in a different terminal

Am I supposed to run a specific version of selenium server. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

macOS Sierra with Safari 10.0.2 needs the new Safari Driver. The Safari webdriver 2.48.0 extenson is for Safari 9 and lower.

There are some issues with the new Safari driver, see also [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3968) and search Google ;-).

Keep in mind that for example the Wait For Angular doesn't work, to avoid that use `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! I'll just stick with 2.53.1 for the safari tests and will probably upgrade once they fix issues with the new safari driver